# Add attribute group to only 1 attribute set

Tags: magento-1, attribute-set

I use this code to add attribute group `'test1'` into attribute set `'test'`. But it always add to all attribute sets.

```
$attributeSetId = $model->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','test');

$installer->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'test1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    $attribute_set_name = 'your attribute set name here';
$group_name = 'your attribute group here';
$attribute_code = 'your attribute code here';

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

//-------------- add attribute to set and group
$attribute_set_id=$setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_name);
$attribute_group_id=$setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
$attribute_id=$setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attribute_code);

$setup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730103/how-can-a-attribute-be-assigned-to-specific-attribute-set-programmatically-via-m